# Footline placement after \begin{document}

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, header-footer

I'm trying to place an image as a border in the footer (`footline`) of a `beamer` presentation. I've noticed that if I use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[large]` after the `\begin{document}`, the vertical placement is too low to show the image. If I use it before `\begin{document}`, then it gets placed correctly. In the final presentation, some slides (such as the title slide) will have this, but more will not, which is why I don't want to set it globally above `\begin{document}` and then suppress it on the slides which don't have it.

What I'm trying to do would look like:

```
\defbeamertheme{footline}{large}{
      \leavevmode
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{images/banner.pdf}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
          \node at (-.845\paperwidth,.05\paperheight) {
          \includegraphics[width=.15\paperwidth]{images/logo.png}
          };
      \end{tikzpicture}
 }

 \begin{document}
 {\setbeamertemplate{footline}[large]
     \begin{frame}
         \titlepage
     \end{frame}
 }
 \begin{frame}{Frame without footline}
     Text
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by recalculating head and foot dimension by `\beamer@calculateheadfoot`.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Here is the Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{large}{
      \leavevmode
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{images/banner.pdf}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
          \node at (-.845\paperwidth,.05\paperheight) {
          \includegraphics[width=.15\paperwidth]{images/logo.png}
          };
      \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand*{\resetsize}{\csname beamer@calculateheadfoot\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\enablefoot}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[large]
  \resetsize
}
\newcommand*{\disablefoot}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
  \resetsize
}
\begin{document}
\enablefoot
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\disablefoot
\begin{frame}{Frame without footline}
  Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

- I used `\csname beamer@calculateheadfoot\endcsname` because this definition would cause an error:

  ```
  \newcommand*{\resetsize}{%
    \makeatletter
    \beamer@calculateheadfoot
    \makeatother}
  ```
- I defined switches instead of using grouping by braces, because in my test document this method produced an additional empty frame.

Answer (score 0):

With the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/e5c868041cb51c278420d0b4189693ed569ee3d9) (should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer), beamer now recalculates the head- and footheight at the start of each frame, so your code now works out of the box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{large}{
      \leavevmode
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
          \node at (-.845\paperwidth,.05\paperheight) {
          \includegraphics[width=.15\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}
          };
      \end{tikzpicture}
 }
 
 \title{text}

 \begin{document}
 {\setbeamertemplate{footline}[large]
     \begin{frame}
         \titlepage
     \end{frame}
 }
 \begin{frame}{Frame without footline}
     Text
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```